# How to change Exception type JWT Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, jwt

Now when tokes is expired it returns message: `Token has expired`. How change this message and how change default exception on custom?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Handler.php

may be you just need to check the exception instance and send the message you want to send to end point.

Something like this should work fine.

```
public function render($request, Exception $exception)
    if ($exception instanceof \Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\TokenInvalidException) {
       return $request->expectsJson()
          ? response()->json([
               'status' => 401,
               'response' => 'Your message'
          ]) : abort(201);
      }
}
```

Comment: No I can not catch it is differ type

Comment: @OPV Are you doing this on Kernel.php `render` method?

Comment: @OPV render method `Exception $exception`, so we should use `$exception`, we were using `$e`, I have edited my answer please check now.

Comment: Yes, I checked, I use it in render

Comment: `if ($exception instanceof \Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\TokenInvalidException) {
   
   return response()->json(['errors' => $exception->getMessage()], 401);
  }`

Comment: @OPV check your log file and let me know the error, that is logged there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193220/discussion-between-prafulla-kumar-sahu-and-opv).